# MarkLogic Task server uses only one thread

Tags: multithreading, marklogic, spawn

I have a query that needs to be run in a collection of 300,000 documents. I used `xdmp:spawn-function()`,
but when I look to the task server it only uses 1 thread to perform the query whereas in the server specifications, the max number of threads is 16. How can I use all of the threads to process the query!?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
import module namespace entity="http://marklogic.com/entity" 
    at "/MarkLogic/entity.xqy";
declare variable $input := sem:sparql-values(
"
// Retrieve 300,000 docs 
", map:map());

let $total-records := 300000
let $batch-size := 1000
let $input-size := fn:count($input)
let $num-batches :=  xs:int(math:ceil($input-size div $batch-size ))
let $result :=
   for $records in 1 to fn:ceiling($total-records  div $batch-size )
   return
    xdmp:spawn-function
    (
    function() {
     for $each in $input
     return terms // Search for specific terms   
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <result>true</result>
      <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
    </options>)
return ($result)
```

Comment: HI.  Can you please share a sample of the code that you are using with spawn function?   This may help people diagnose what is going on.  Example - a loop inside of spawn function is a single thread, but spawn function inside inside of a loop would spawn many tasks to the queue and use the threads.  Also explain what you are trying to accomplish as spawn function runs on one server and is not resilient. These are things to take into account

Comment: In addition to David's comment, I guess a key question is: how do you reach the conclusion that the TS uses only 1 thread?

Comment: script added . By take a look at the status of the task server in the admin interface

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that your code is only using one thread.  If I loop over 10 times and sleep for 10 seconds with a return, I can see 10 threads running.

For your code, A few things:

Could still time out. You use the "result" option that requires the initiating thread to wait until all spawned threads have returned their value.

Imagine you have 16 threads available and in use. At a  window size of 1000, and 3000 batches, then consider the amount of time a batch of 1000 takes to run.

- Let's assume 5 seconds per batch.
- The processing time would be 5s * (3000/16) = 5s * 188 = 937 sec = 15.6 min
- so, your calling thread would have to run for over 15 minutes. If your timeout was lower that that, then the final call would fail with a timeout( the call (returning $result)) even with the spawned tasks completing.

This is unlikely what you had meant to do. However, for fast-running batches, then this is an OK way to do work in parallel - assuming there is nothing else consuming the task queue that could then get in the middle of your processing.

Now for your code sample. The code actually:

- loops from 1 to 300 and spawns 300 tasks (the $recods variable)
- Then in the 300 tasks, it loops over each of 300000 items in $input.

I ran it in a similar fashion to see what was happening with your pagination code - but also added a tiny sleep:

```
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
import module namespace entity="http://marklogic.com/entity" 
    at "/MarkLogic/entity.xqy";

let $total-records := 300000
let $input := for $x in (1 to $total-records) return $x
let $batch-size := 1000
let $input-size := fn:count($input)
let $num-batches :=  xs:int(math:ceil($input-size div $batch-size ))
let $result :=
   for $records in 1 to fn:ceiling($total-records  div $batch-size )
   return
    xdmp:spawn-function
    (
    function() {
     let $_ := xdmp:eager(xdmp:sleep(300))
     return fn:min($records) (: start of set :)   
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <result>true</result>
      <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
    </options>)
return ($input-size, $num-batches, $result)
```

This code (essentially your sample) shows:

- 16 threads used
- However, it is not actually batching 300 chunks of 1000 each - it is just the first 300 items in total. There is no real chunking - just 1-300

And when I take away my sleep, it "appears" to only use one thread because it is done soo soo fast in my sample.

The following modified code below would batch a sequence of inputs. As with the sample above, I added a sleep so that I could see the multiple threads:

```
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
import module namespace entity="http://marklogic.com/entity" 
    at "/MarkLogic/entity.xqy";

let $input := for $x in (1 to 300000) return "record-" || $x
let $batch-size := 1000
let $input-size := fn:count($input)
let $num-batches :=  xs:int(math:ceil($input-size div $batch-size ))
let $result :=
   for $step in 1 to fn:ceiling($input-size  div $batch-size )       
   let $start := ($batch-size * $step) - $batch-size + 1
   let $end := $start + $batch-size - 1 return
    xdmp:spawn-function
    (
    function() {
      let $_ := xdmp:sleep(300)
      let $batch := $input[$start, $end]
      return fn:string-join(("batch[",xs:string($step),"] ",$batch[1], " ... ", $batch[last()]), "")
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <result>true</result>
      <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
    </options>)
return $result
```

Resulting in:

```
batch[1] record-1 ... record-1000
batch[2] record-1001 ... record-2000
batch[3] record-2001 ... record-3000
batch[4] record-3001 ... record-4000
batch[300] record-299001 ... record-300000
```

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend using taskbot to do server-side batching, although there might also be compelling reasons to not do the orchestration server-side at all, but use external tools like Corb2 or NiFi or even MLCP to go over large volumes in a controllable manner:

- https://github.com/mblakele/taskbot
- https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb/
- https://nifi.apache.org/

HTH!